# Django Query: Date Aggregation

Tags: django, django-models

I'm a Django newbie who needs your help

Have this database model:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    account_id=models.ForeignKey(Account)
    date=models.DateTimeField()
    balance=models.FloatField()
```

The table looks like this:

```
account_id   date      balance
0001         2010-1-1  1000
0001         2011-1-1  2000
0002         2010-1-1  1000
0002         2011-1-1  2000
```

What I want is: given a datetime, make a query that returns the most recent record of each account before that datetime. For example:

given datetime: `2010-12-1` returns:

```
0001         2010-1-1   1000
0002         2010-1-1   1000
```

How to make such query via Django's Query API gracefully?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far from a simple question. There's no way to do it with a single query. See [my blog entry](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/08/14/getting-related-item-aggregate/) for a technique that gets it in two.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. You are right, it's quite so complicated to me :-) . Your blog is really helpful. My goal is achieved with two queries and some python processing. Cheers!